Spring Security Oauth2 Access Token in ReactJS client
What would be the best way to store JWT access tokens received from the Spring Security Authorization server in a ReactJS client? I didnt find anywhere in the documentation whether its possible to configure the Authorization server to send the token in http only cookie.
Tried sending the access token to a custom endpoint and have it returned as an http cookie, but that seemed to have broken the flow between the resource and auth. server somehow

I don't recommend doing this, and as such have not looked at documenting such a practice. See How-to: Authenticate a Single Page App which recommends the BFF pattern as an alternative as in ch4mp's answer.

The access token is expected by resource servers as an Authorization header, not as a cookie.
This can be achieved from a single-page application at the price of making it a public client and having the token accessible to the application code (as well as the many 3rd parties dependencies code).
To mitigate the risks of the above, it is now recommended to use confidential clients (on the backend) rather than public ones (in the frontend), even with PKCE, and to keep tokens in the backend (don't expose it to the frontend, even as http-only cookies).
I wrote an article on Baeldung to authorize requests with a session cookie (and cookie-based protection against CSRF) between the front and back ends. I use spring-cloud-gateway configured with oauth2Login and with the TokenRelay filter. This makes it an OAuth2 BFF which replaces the session cookie with the access token in session before forwarding a request to a resource server.
